# Unexpected logcat with idle Android phone

Tags: android-studio, logcat

I am attempting to debug an error using logcat in Android Studio on my testing device, a Galaxy s9 plus running Pie. Suddenly I have a really weird and annoying logcat output making it hard to veiw events:

```
2019-03-01 10:49:15.024 17645-17645/? I/DBG_FMMDM: [6.9.22][Line:55][a] xdmGetAccountRegistration : true
2019-03-01 10:49:15.024 17645-17645/? I/DBG_FMMDM: [6.9.22][Line:47][onDestroy] XDM ALERT REAMINED, SO RESTART DM SERVICE
2019-03-01 10:49:15.024 17645-17645/? I/DBG_FMMDM: [6.9.22][Line:2][a] FMM Application Start !
2019-03-01 10:49:15.028 17645-17645/? I/DBG_FMMDM: [6.9.22][Line:5][onCreate] XDM Service onCreate
2019-03-01 10:49:15.029 17645-17645/? I/DBG_FMMDM: [6.9.22][Line:20][onCreate] Device ID is null!!, service not start !
2019-03-01 10:49:15.030 17645-17645/? I/DBG_FMMDM: [6.9.22][Line:3][onStartCommand] 
2019-03-01 10:49:15.030 17645-17645/? I/DBG_FMMDM: [6.9.22][Line:2][onDestroy] onDestroy
2019-03-01 10:49:15.037 17645-17645/? I/DBG_FMMDM: [6.9.22][Line:30][a] Samsung Account Exist !!!
2019-03-01 10:49:15.038 17645-17645/? E/DBG_FMMDM: Warning!!! [6.9.22][Line:15][a] java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.fmm.dm.b.a.x com.fmm.dm.b.a.ac.g' on a null object reference
```

This output runs over and over, to the point that my logcat is completely populated and there is no way to scroll up to see past outputs.

I have no idea what `I/DBG_FMMDM` is and why it is attempting to read from `com.fmm.dm.b.a.x` (whatever that is).

Has anyone seen this type of output before?

My testing device is a Galaxy s9 plus running Pie

Comment: That's just various output from everything. You'll need to add a filter and filter by your app unless you want to see **all** the logs the system and any other running debug apps produce

Comment: But it's the same 9 lines repeating. I have never seen logs like this before that never stop and continually print the same output.

Comment: Just ignore it. There's nothing you can do about it anyways. Use the app-based filters, or create your own and you'll see the output you want to. If you're asking about the output specifically, and it's from the OS as I suspect, you're on the wrong site and should ask on [android.se] instead. Also, an idle phone isn't as idle as you'd expect - there's a lot going on under the hood that you don't see.

Comment: When I say idle I mean there is no user created processes, only startup. This log may in fact be a daemon, but it is a very peculiar one. I'll post the question to the thread you recommended. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would want to filter your logs - for example, filter your logs so that you will only see your current application related logs. 
Now, if you are debugging error I would recommend to go to your logcat and filter the results by error(it just makes thing a lot comfortable).
**In this image, you can see where to filter your log results:**
[image]

As you can see you can choose what do you want to filter by using this menu.

Comment: Yes I know how to filter the logcat. My concern is with the particular output in the question. I've been using logcat for years and have never seen such an aggressive and recursive log out. That is much for concern.

Comment: Could it be that this is just the system log for this particular device? is the same happening on other devices?

Comment: It is, in fact, a device-specific problem. Weird, I'll post the question to [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/), it may be due to the recent version upgrade for Galaxy or it may be a virus on the device. Anywho, thank you for your help.